# C# database application using Ms access 2010

Tags: c#

I am developing a database application on C# using MS Access for my perfume shop, i have created a table in ms access, named as "MIX", having columns (Brand name,Stock quantity,Retail price,Original price). I want to add their field through C# window form that i have created.

I am trying the following query for inserting my data but all the time i am getting an error "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        string str = string.Format("Insert into MIX([Brand name],Stock quantity,Retail price,Original price)Values('" + textBox1.Text + "'," + textBox2.Text + "," + textBox3.Text + "," + textBox4.Text + ")");
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str,con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Successfull");
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Please show the value of `str` in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Four things:

1. You don't need `string.Format` when you're just concatenating values
2. Column names with spaces must be surrounded by square brackets:

   ```
   string str = "Insert into MIX " + 
                "([Brand name],[Stock quantity],[Retail price],[Original price]) " + 
                "Values('" + textBox1.Text + "'," + textBox2.Text + "," + textBox3.Text + "," + textBox4.Text + ")";
   ```
3. You should learn how to use Parameters instead of concatenating SQL:

   ```
   string str = "Insert into MIX " + 
                "([Brand name],[Stock quantity],[Retail price],[Original price]) " + 
                "Values (?,?,?,?)");
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str,con);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("brand",textBox1.Text);
   ... repeat for other values
   ```
4. It appears you're reusing a shared `OleDbConnection` object.  This is not a best practice since connections are pooled in .NET and are cheap to recreate after the first usage, and you don't hae to worry about leaving a connection open throughout the life of your application.

Comment: Thanks D Stanley. it works. Actually i am new to MS access and C#. I hope i can learn much through this.

Comment: @user3043233 Glad it works - yes there are several "best practices" when working with commands that unfortunately aren't taught in most tutorials.  Good luck in your learning!

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad idea since the values are being directly dropped into the query, but the problem you are experiencing is the multi-word column names:

```
Insert into MIX([Brand name],Stock quantity,Retail price,Original price)
```

These need to have bracket around them:

```
Insert into MIX([Brand name],[Stock quantity],[Retail price],[Original price])[
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose column names that contain spaces insquare brackets []. Also, you need to use parameters instead of concatenating values to the SQL query like that. Google "SQL injection attack" to know the reason why.

```
Insert into MIX([Brand name],[Stock quantity],[Retail price],[Original price])Values(?,?,?,?)
```

You *replace* those ?'s with values this way:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Textbox1.text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Textbox2.text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Textbox3.text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Textbox4.text);
```

Be aware that the order matters.